# Firebase error casting to object Can't convert object of type java.lang.Boolean to type

Tags: android, object, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get all the values from a node in firebase and convert them to my object (I don't want to create a map of the values and set each one to my object) I'm using this code below

```
dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    contactRef = 
dbRef.child(Constants.USERS).child(userId).child(Constants.CONTACTS);
    contactRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Contact contact = ds.getValue(Contact.class);
            }
        }
```

but this gives me the error

```
Can't convert object of type java.lang.Boolean to type ...Objects.Contact
```

if I instead just print the values from the datasnapshot I get my expected output (values have been removed for brevity)

```
Log.d(TAG,ds.toString());

key = blocked, value = 
key = msg_time_stamp, value = 
key = registeredToken, value = 
key = unread, value = 
key = user_id, value = 
key = user_image, value = 
key = user_name, value = 
key = user_number, value = 
key = user_recent_message, value =  
key = user_small_image, value = 
key = user_status, value =  
key = user_time_stamp, value =
```

which matches my class

```
private String registeredToken;
private String user_id;
private String user_name;
private String user_status;
private String user_number;
private String user_image;
private String user_small_image;
private long user_time_stamp;
private String user_recent_message;
private long msg_time_stamp;
private Boolean blocked;
private int unread;
```

anybody know why this might fail? here is my full Contacts object class

```
public class Contact implements Parcelable {

public static final Creator CREATOR = new Creator() {
    public Contact createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
        return new Contact(parcel);
    }

    public Contact[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Contact[size];
    }
};


private String registeredToken;
private String user_id;
private String user_name;
private String user_status;
private String user_number;
private String user_image;
private String user_small_image;
private long user_time_stamp;
private String user_recent_message;
private long msg_time_stamp;
private Boolean blocked;
private int unread;

public Contact() {
}

public String getUser_name() {
    return this.user_name;
}

public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
    this.user_name = user_name;
}

public String getUser_status() {
    return this.user_status;
}

public void setUser_status(String user_status) {
    this.user_status = user_status;
}

public String getUser_id() {
    return this.user_id;
}

public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
    this.user_id = user_id;
}

public String getUser_number() {
    return this.user_number;
}

public void setUser_number(String user_number) {
    this.user_number = user_number;
}

public String getUser_image() {
    return this.user_image;
}

public void setUser_image(String user_image) {
    this.user_image = user_image;
}

public String getUser_small_image() {
    return user_small_image;
}

public void setUser_small_image(String user_small_image) {
    this.user_small_image = user_small_image;
}

public long getUser_time_stamp() {
    return this.user_time_stamp;
}

public void setUser_time_stamp(long user_time_stamp) {
    this.user_time_stamp = user_time_stamp;
}

public String getUser_recent_message() {
    return this.user_recent_message;
}

public void setUser_recent_message(String user_recent_message) {
    this.user_recent_message = user_recent_message;
}

public Boolean getBlocked() {
    return this.blocked;
}

public void setBlocked(Boolean blocked) {
    this.blocked = blocked;
}

public int getUnread() {
    return this.unread;
}

public void setUnread(int unread) {
    this.unread = unread;
}

public long getMsg_time_stamp() {
    return this.msg_time_stamp;
}

public void setMsg_time_stamp(long msg_time_stamp) {
    this.msg_time_stamp = msg_time_stamp;
}

public String getRegisteredToken() {
    return registeredToken;
}

public void setRegisteredToken(String registeredToken) {
    this.registeredToken = registeredToken;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object otherUserObject) {
    if (!(otherUserObject instanceof Contact)) {
        return false;
    }
    Contact that = (Contact) otherUserObject;
    if (this.user_recent_message != null && that.user_recent_message != null){
        return this.user_name.equals(that.user_name)
                && this.user_status.equals(that.user_status)
                && this.user_id.equals(that.user_id)
                && this.user_number.equals(that.user_number)
                && this.user_image.equals(that.user_image)
                && this.user_small_image.equals(that.user_small_image)
                && this.user_recent_message.equals(that.user_recent_message)
                && this.unread == that.unread
                && this.blocked == that.blocked
                && this.user_time_stamp == that.user_time_stamp
                && this.msg_time_stamp == that.msg_time_stamp
                && this.registeredToken.equals(that.registeredToken)
                ;
    }
    else{
        return this.user_name.equals(that.user_name)
                && this.user_status.equals(that.user_status)
                && this.user_id.equals(that.user_id)
                && this.user_number.equals(that.user_number)
                && this.user_image.equals(that.user_image)
                && this.user_small_image.equals(that.user_small_image)
                && this.blocked == that.blocked
                && this.unread == that.unread
                && this.user_time_stamp == that.user_time_stamp
                && this.registeredToken.equals(that.registeredToken)
                ;
    }
}

private Contact(Parcel in){
    this.user_name = in.readString();
    this.user_status =  in.readString();
    this.user_id = in.readString();
    this.user_number = in.readString();
    this.user_image = in.readString();
    this.user_small_image = in.readString();
    this.user_time_stamp = in.readLong();
    this.user_recent_message = in.readString();
    this.msg_time_stamp = in.readLong();
    this.blocked = in.readInt() != 0;
    this.unread = in.readInt();
    this.registeredToken = in.readString();
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.user_name);
    dest.writeString(this.user_status);
    dest.writeString(this.user_id);
    dest.writeString(this.user_number);
    dest.writeString(this.user_image);
    dest.writeString(this.user_small_image);
    dest.writeLong(this.user_time_stamp);
    dest.writeString(this.user_recent_message);
    dest.writeLong(this.msg_time_stamp);
    dest.writeInt(this.blocked ? 1 : 0);
    dest.writeInt(this.unread);
    dest.writeString(this.registeredToken);
}


public static class ContactsList {
    private List<Contact> contactsList;
    public List<Contact> getContactList() {
        return contactsList;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

swapped child event listener for standard event listener apparently that was my issue